# getting syntax error in case statement in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am getting a syntax error in case statement in mysql.
1064- you have an error in your sql statement.

```
insert into
abc_table(release_date,title,detail,num)  
select model1.release_date,model1.title,model1.detail,model1.num
CASE 
WHEN model1.num= 0 THEN 3
WHEN model1.num= 1 THEN 1
WHEN model1.num= 2 THEN 2
END AS model1.num
from def_table  model1
```

Is this syntax is correct in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two columns for `model1.num`:

```
insert into abc_table(release_date,title,detail,num)  
select model1.release_date,
   model1.title,
   model1.detail,
   model1.num -- <-- extra
   CASE 
      WHEN model1.num= 0 THEN 3
      WHEN model1.num= 1 THEN 1
      WHEN model1.num= 2 THEN 2
      END AS num
from def_table  model1
```

Your code should be:

```
insert into abc_table(release_date,title,detail,num)  
select model1.release_date,
   model1.title,
   model1.detail,
   CASE 
      WHEN model1.num= 0 THEN 3
      WHEN model1.num= 1 THEN 1
      WHEN model1.num= 2 THEN 2
      END AS num
from def_table  model1
```

*Note:* Sometimes, formatting your code will help find these errors. It can be difficult to see when all of the columns are in one row.

Comment: Pretty fast on the fiddle there bluefeet!

Comment: Thanks bluefeet but what if "num" datatype is enum then what?

Comment: @Java_NewBie I don't understand your question.  Is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

you missed one comma

```
insert into
abc_table(release_date,title,detail,num)  
select model1.release_date,model1.title,model1.detail,
CASE 
WHEN model1.num= 0 THEN 3
WHEN model1.num= 1 THEN 1
WHEN model1.num= 2 THEN 2
END AS model1.num
from def_table  model1
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra column in this select statement..

```
select model1.release_date,model1.title,model1.detail,model1.num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into abc_table(release_date,title,detail,num)  
select m.release_date
     , m.title
     , m.detail
     , CASE WHEN m.num = 0 THEN 3
            WHEN m.num= 1 THEN 1
            WHEN m.num= 2 THEN 2
        END num
  FROM def_table m;
```